# Rate Exceeded in AWS Lambda tutorial

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm running the AWS Lambda tutorial at https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-serverless-code/ and I'm getting a strange error. I'm on step 5, where it says to run the test a few times to generate some metrics to view. After running my test 3 times, I started getting this error message:

`Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Rate Exceeded.`

What? I'm new to lambda, but I'm not doing anything complicated or time consuming, I'm just running the the AWS tutorial. Can anyone tell me how to get past this?

Comment: Are you doing this in an AWS account that's being shared with other users/applications? [Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) are shared at the account level

Comment: It's a personal account that I created for these tutorials.

Comment: Mine is the only account in my organization.